Discrepancy in qpOASES Optimal Solutions Between C++ and MATLAB Implementations
I have implemented a quadratic programming problem using qpOASES in MATLAB and C++. The optimal solutions differ despite using the same matrices and vectors in both environments. The MATLAB implementation produces valid solutions (as of my best guess), confirmed by the Webots simulation interface. However, the C++ implementation, when compiled and executed, does not provide a correct solution, leading to performance issues in the Webots environment. Here I have provided a simple yet similar example related to my problem. Upon testing on both platforms, still got different outputs.
MATLAB Code (R2022a)
% Define the matrix H (12 by 12)
H = [1.7201, 0.981765, 0, -1.70402, 0.981765, 0, 1.7161, -1.15451, 0, -1.70402, -1.15451, 0;
     0.981765, 0.573682, 0, -0.981765, 0.569682, 0, 0.981765, -0.656776, 0, -0.981765, -0.656776, 0;
     0, 0, 0.0153304, 0, 0, 0.000762503, 0, 0, 0.00687851, 0, 0, -0.00368936;
     -1.70402, -0.981765, 0, 1.7201, -0.981765, 0, -1.70402, 1.15451, 0, 1.7161, 1.15451, 0;
     0.981765, 0.569682, 0, -0.981765, 0.573682, 0, 0.981765, -0.656776, 0, -0.981765, -0.656776, 0;
     0, 0, 0.000762503, 0, 0, 0.0135145, 0, 0, -0.00171378, 0, 0, 0.00703826;
     1.7161, 0.981765, 0, -1.70402, 0.981765, 0, 1.7201, -1.15451, 0, -1.70402, -1.15451, 0;
     -1.15451, -0.656776, 0, 1.15451, -0.656776, 0, -1.15451, 0.789478, 0, 1.15451, 0.785478, 0;
     0, 0, 0.00687851, 0, 0, -0.00171378, 0, 0, 0.0139643, 0, 0, 0.00137201;
     -1.70402, -0.981765, 0, 1.7161, -0.981765, 0, -1.70402, 1.15451, 0, 1.7201, 1.15451, 0;
     -1.15451, -0.656776, 0, 1.15451, -0.656776, 0, -1.15451, 0.785478, 0, 1.15451, 0.789478, 0;
     0, 0, -0.00368936, 0, 0, 0.00703826, 0, 0, 0.00137201, 0, 0, 0.0160996];

% Define the the vector g (12 by 1)
g = [117.537; 67.4661; -0.393848; -117.52; 67.4661; -0.39092; 117.537; -79.355; -0.393697; -117.52; -79.355; -0.39077];

% Define Matrix A (20 by 12)
A = [0.666667, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
    -0.666667, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
    0, 0.666667, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
    0, -0.666667, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
    0, 0, 0, 0.666667, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
    0, 0, 0, -0.666667, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.666667, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
    0, 0, 0, 0, -0.666667, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.666667, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0;
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.666667, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0;
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.666667, 1, 0, 0, 0;
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.666667, 1, 0, 0, 0;
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0;
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.666667, 0, 1;
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.666667, 0, 1;
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.666667, 1;
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.666667, 1;
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1];

% Define the constraint vector lower bounds for A matrix lbA (20 by 1)
lbA = zeros(20, 1);

% Define the constraint vector upper bounds for A matrix ubA (20 by 1)
ubA = [150; 150; 150; 150; 120; 150; 150; 150; 150; 120; 150; 150; 150; 150; 120; 150; 150; 150; 150; 120];

% Solve the QP problem using qpOASES
[x,fval,exitflag,iter,lambda] = qpOASES(H, g, A, [], [], lbA, ubA, []);
% Output the result
disp('Optimal solution:');
disp(x);


**C++ Code (Microsoft Visual Studio 2019) **
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <qpOASES.hpp>

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace qpOASES;

int main()
{
    USING_NAMESPACE_QPOASES;

    // Initialize the qpOASES library
    QProblem qp(12, 20); // 12 variables, 20 constraints

    // Set up the matrices and vectors as shown in the images
    MatrixXd H(12, 12);
    H << 1.7201, 0.981765, 0, -1.70402, 0.981765, 0, 1.7161, -1.15451, 0, -1.70402, -1.15451, 0,
        0.981765, 0.573682, 0, -0.981765, 0.569682, 0, 0.981765, -0.656776, 0, -0.981765, -0.656776, 0,
        0, 0, 0.0153304, 0, 0, 0.000762503, 0, 0, 0.00687851, 0, 0, -0.00368936,
        -1.70402, -0.981765, 0, 1.7201, -0.981765, 0, -1.70402, 1.15451, 0, 1.7161, 1.15451, 0,
        0.981765, 0.569682, 0, -0.981765, 0.573682, 0, 0.981765, -0.656776, 0, -0.981765, -0.656776, 0,
        0, 0, 0.000762503, 0, 0, 0.0135145, 0, 0, -0.00171378, 0, 0, 0.00703826,
        1.7161, 0.981765, 0, -1.70402, 0.981765, 0, 1.7201, -1.15451, 0, -1.70402, -1.15451, 0,
        -1.15451, -0.656776, 0, 1.15451, -0.656776, 0, -1.15451, 0.789478, 0, 1.15451, 0.785478, 0,
        0, 0, 0.00687851, 0, 0, -0.00171378, 0, 0, 0.0139643, 0, 0, 0.00137201,
        -1.70402, -0.981765, 0, 1.7161, -0.981765, 0, -1.70402, 1.15451, 0, 1.7201, 1.15451, 0,
        -1.15451, -0.656776, 0, 1.15451, -0.656776, 0, -1.15451, 0.785478, 0, 1.15451, 0.789478, 0,
        0, 0, -0.00368936, 0, 0, 0.00703826, 0, 0, 0.00137201, 0, 0, 0.0160996;

    VectorXd g(12);
    g << 117.537, 67.4661, -0.393848, -117.52, 67.4661, -0.39092, 117.537, -79.355, -0.393697, -117.52, -79.355, -0.39077;

    MatrixXd A(20, 12);
    A << 0.666667, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        -0.666667, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0.666667, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, -0.666667, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0.666667, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, -0.666667, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0.666667, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, -0.666667, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.666667, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.666667, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.666667, 1, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.666667, 1, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.666667, 0, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.666667, 0, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.666667, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.666667, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1;

    VectorXd lbA = VectorXd::Zero(20);
    VectorXd ubA(20);
    ubA << 150, 150, 150, 150, 120, 150, 150, 150, 150, 120, 150, 150, 150, 150, 120, 150, 150, 150, 150, 120;

    // Set the number of working set recalculations (iterations)
    int nWSR = 100;

    // Solve the QP problem
    returnValue status = qp.init(H.data(), g.data(), A.data(), nullptr, nullptr, lbA.data(), ubA.data(), nWSR);

    // Retrieve the solution
    VectorXd x(12);
    qp.getPrimalSolution(x.data());

    

    // Check if the problem was solved successfully
    if (status == SUCCESSFUL_RETURN)
    {
        qp.getPrimalSolution(x.data());
        std::cout << "Successful: Optimal solution: " << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to solve the QP problem. Status: " << status << std::endl;
    }

    // Output the result
    std::cout << "Optimal solution:" << std::endl << x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}


Output in MATLAB and C++ after qpOASES optimization
The optimal solution vector obtained after the qpOASES operation in both environments is:
MATLAB, C++ output
Given that both implementations use the same matrices and vectors (H, g, A, lbA ubA), I am confused by the discrepancy in the solutions. Could there be an issue with the configuration or usage of qpOASES in the C++ code? Any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

This is a matrix data conversion problem with Eigen. If you store your constraint matrix data like
double A_data[12*20] = {
    0.666667, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    -0.666667, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0.666667, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, -0.666667, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0.666667, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, -0.666667, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.666667, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, -0.666667, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.666667, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.666667, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.666667, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.666667, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.666667, 0, 1,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.666667, 0, 1,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.666667, 1,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.666667, 1,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1};

and pass A_data instead of A.data() to qp.init, you get what you expect. The A.data() you are using is in column major format, i.e., the array starts with 0.666667, -0.666667, 0, ...
The problem does not appear for the Hessian because H is symmetric.
Alternatively, you can define your constraint matrix as
Eigen::Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor> A(20, 12);

(see https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStorageOrders.html).
Regarding the additional questions:

Why do I need to define matrix A in row-major order in C++ when using qpOASES, but I don't need to do this in MATLAB? If MATLAB also stores matrices in column-major order, why does qpOASES work correctly without explicitly specifying the row-major format?

Because the Matlab interface takes care of the conversion. In C++, you are responsible for providing the matrix data in the correct format.

Why does the Hessian matrix H produce identical results regardless of whether it's stored in a row-major or column-major format in Eigen, while matrix A does not?

When you interpret a square, column major formatted matrix in row major format, you obtain the transposed matrix. The Hessian is a symmetric matrix, i.e., it is equal to its transpose.

If you had compiled a minimum reproducible example without the use of Eigen, you would have detected the problem yourself.
